# sum last 7 days of sales in new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data set:

[image]

I want to create a new column that sums the last 7 days of sales. So the query result should look be the following:

[image]

Pls help
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your data set in something other than an image?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Also, what kind of SQL?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: You have a lot of data in your table that would be much better suited to be in a Calendar Table (like `month number`, `month name`, `week`, `day`, `month period`, `week period`).  And a Calendar Table would make it much easier and more accurate to get the data you're looking for.

Answer (score 8):

In standard SQL, you would use a window function -- assuming you have data for each day:

```
select t.*,
       sum(sales) over (partition by itemid order by date rows between 6 preceding and current row) as sales_7
from t;
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use  sum() aggregate function and group by

```
    select country,itemid,year,monthnumber,week sum(sales) as sales_last_7days  from your_table

    where date>=DATEADD(day, -7, getdate())  and date< getdate()

    group by country,itemid,year,monthnumber,week
```

Answer (score 1):

with window:

```
select (list other columns here), sum(sum(sales)) over 
    (partition by week
     order by day
     rows between 6 preceding and current row)
from table
group by date, week;
```

note that week doesen't change group by beacause a date is reffered to one week only, but it is needed in window.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are working with SQL Server if so, then you can use `apply` :

```
select t.*, t1.[last7day]
from table t outer apply
     (select sum(t1.sales) as [last7day]
      from table t1
      where t.itemid = t1.itemid  and 
            t1.date <= dateadd(day, -6, t.dt)
     ) t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ***don't*** have exactly one day for each row, for example if you have a list of transactions...

The below example completely confused me the first time I saw it, so I've tried to comment as much as I can to explain what's happening.

Suppose we have a table `tbl` with date column `dt` and amount column `amt`, and for each date in `tbl` we want to return a rolling sum of the amount from the current day and the past 6 days.

```
select distinct  -- see note after code on what this distinct is doing.
    dt
    , ( -- Has to be in brackets to denote we're returning 1 value per row.
        -- for each row of T1:
        select sum(b.amt)  -- the sum of amounts in T2. The where clause will restrict which rows in T2 will be summed.
        from tbl T2
        where T2.dt between T1.dt - 6 and T1.dt  -- for each row in T1, give me all rows in T2 where the date is between 6 days before this T1 row's date and T1 row's date, giving us our rolling sum
        -- WARNING: CHECK YOUR VERSION OF SQL FOR HOW TO SUBTRACT DAYS FROM A DATE, I'VE MADE IT (T1.dt - 6) FOR SIMPLICITY
        -- we don't need a group by, because we're returning one value for each row in T1
    )
from tbl T1
```

We have a main version of `tbl`, aliased `T1`. We then have a secondary table, aliased `T2`. For each row in `T1`, we're going to ask for *a set of rows* in `T2` that we're going to sum *before* giving it to our main query.

To understand what's happening, run the code without the `distinct`. You'll notice that we have the same number of rows as in `tbl`, because the `T2` statement is happening for every row in `T1`.

Notes:

- If you have any days for which no rows exist in your table *you will not get a calculation for this day*. To be certain this doesn't happen, join your table to a table containing a distinct list of consecutive dates, and use this as your date column.
- If you have nulls in your amount column the calculation will still work, but if the rolling average contains only nulls you will have null instead of 0 as your result. If that troubles you convert all your nulls to zero's before (or after) you use the query.
- The beginning of the period will have a 'ramp up'. But this would be the same whatever method you use to do a rolling sum. If it bothers you, don't return the first 6 days.

Finally a worked example if you're playing along at home using SQL Server:

```
with tbl as (
     -- a list of transactions from 1.10.2019 to 14.10.2019
    select cast('2019-10-01' as date) dt, 1 amt
    union select cast('2019-10-02' as date), 4
    union select cast('2019-10-01' as date), 10
    union select cast('2019-10-03' as date), 3
    union select cast('2019-10-04' as date), 20
    union select cast('2019-10-04' as date), 2
    union select cast('2019-10-04' as date), 12
    union select cast('2019-10-04' as date), 17
    union select cast('2019-10-05' as date), null -- a whole week of null values because we all had the week off... I hope this data wasn't important
    union select cast('2019-10-06' as date), null
    union select cast('2019-10-07' as date), null
    union select cast('2019-10-08' as date), null
    union select cast('2019-10-09' as date), null
    union select cast('2019-10-10' as date), null
    union select cast('2019-10-10' as date), null
    union select cast('2019-10-10' as date), null
    union select cast('2019-10-11' as date), null
    union select cast('2019-10-12' as date), 1
    union select cast('2019-10-12' as date), 1
    union select cast('2019-10-12' as date), 1
    union select cast('2019-10-12' as date), 1
    union select cast('2019-10-12' as date), 1
    union select cast('2019-10-12' as date), 1
    union select cast('2019-10-13' as date), 2
    union select cast('2019-10-14' as date), 1000
 )
select distinct
    a.dt
    , (
       select sum(b.amt)
       from tbl b
       where b.dt between dateadd(dd, -6, a.dt) and a.dt
   ) past_7_days_amt
from tbl a
```

Returns:

```
+------------+-----------------+
|     dt     | past_7_days_amt |
+------------+-----------------+
| 2019-10-01 | 11              |
| 2019-10-02 | 15              |
| 2019-10-03 | 18              |
| 2019-10-04 | 69              |
| 2019-10-05 | 69              |
| 2019-10-06 | 69              |
| 2019-10-07 | 69              |
| 2019-10-08 | 58              |
| 2019-10-09 | 54              |
| 2019-10-10 | 51              |
| 2019-10-11 | NULL            |
| 2019-10-12 | 1               |
| 2019-10-13 | 3               |
| 2019-10-14 | 1003            |
+------------+-----------------+
```